# Getting a "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" error while explicitly converting to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a surprising error. I check if one record's ID matches the ID of another object:

```
new_post = posts_with_score.detect {|post| post["id"].to_s == original_post.id.to_s }
```

I get an error `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`. This is surprising since both id's are **explicitly** converted into **strings**.

What am I not seeing here? Why is this equality check trying to convert into integers?

Edit:

Here is what `post` inside the detect looks like: `{"time_since_post_in_hours"=>15.810972532939815, "upvote_count"=>324, "id"=>1, "score"=>4.3103601541380465}`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error from this particular line ?

Comment: Yes, was double checking that and it definitely points to this Line number in a particular function. There are no other checks or conversions anywhere nearby either.

Comment: What happens when you do puts post.class inside your block?

Comment: i think `post` inside the block is an array.  the error is about converting a string into integer, not the other way around.

Comment: given the edit, expand detect to use multiple lines. place one line as `post['id']`, another as `original_post.id`, then your conditional as the last line. you should be able to pinpoint the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @jvnill - looks like it is coming from the `post["id"]`

Comment: @DonnyP: what was it?

Comment: in that case, i stand by what i said earlier.  `post` is an array inside the block.  use `debugger` or `pry` and get inside the loop to inspect the value of `post`.  or add the following line inside the loop `(post['id'] rescue nil) || puts post.inspect` so that you can see which `post` is causing the issue

Comment: I was getting this error from an API. It had to do with null or missing values in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way your hash is structured, when you iterate through it, post is an array. So when you do post["id"] Ruby tries to convert your index (a string) into an Integer. That's when you get the error. Notice that the error is "no implicit conversion of **String into Integer**" and not the other way around. So check your hash structure to adjust to what you want.

Comment: Just edited the question since I was checking if `Post` was an array, it looks like `Post` is still a hash

Comment: Would you mind also posting the content of posts_with_score ?